# OTB JCA mail resource adapter?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jca

I'm looking for the best way to implement a JCA resource adapter to read email, transform and queue the message on a message queue.  I am open to any Enterprise stack.

Comment: Have a look at [Creating and Using Custom Java EE Connector Architecture Adapters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/luttikhuizen-adapters-091679.html) which implements a mail adapter. On the other hand, it's not the easiest thing to write a resource adapter. What about using a `@Singleton` with a `@Schedule` method to poll for mails, and new mails are just send once again on a JMS queue? On top of this it's plain JMS.

Comment: Thanks @Beryllium I will followup with this as soon as I can switch back to this project.